# How to not over-use jQuery?

Tags: jquery, performance

Typical jQuery over-use:

```
$('button').click(function() {
  alert('Button clicked: ' + $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Which can be simplified to:

```
$('button').click(function() {
  alert('Button clicked: ' + this.id);
});
```

Which is way faster.

Can you give me any more examples of similar jQuery over-use?

Comment: Poll-type question: Community Wiki?

Comment: I disagree with *way* faster.  This is happening once for 1 click, which is a difference you literally *can't* measure, it'd take tens to hundreds of thousands of iterations to get a measurable difference here.  If it was in a loop, then it's a valid point...in your example though, it's not, at least from a performance standpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO, these aren't things to worry about.

The $ function is incredibly fast, and guarantees cross-browser problems are not going to be a problem. For example, that might work fine right now, but what happens if IE9 comes out and breaks it? If you're using the $ function everywhere, then a fix in one place fixes it everywhere. Not to mention, I can't imagine a case where this would get you any sort of performance increase.

Therefore, unless you're having issues with performance, don't worry about micro-optimizations. jQuery 1.4 had some huge performance increases anyway, so unless you're doing:

```
$('p>a:first-child+input[type=text]~span');
```

all over the place without caching, you're not going to get any return on your time investment.

Answer (score 8):

The second way is faster of course, as it's getting the id property straight from the DOM object, therefore there is at least one less function call.

That said, the difference would anyhow be imperceptible and nothing to fret over, and so I will venture to say that the first example is *not* an example of overuse.

Comment: +1 Exactly. Maybe an example of unneeded use but not overuse.

Answer (score 4):

> "We should forget about small
>   efficiencies, say about 97% of the
>   time: premature optimization is the
>   root of all evil"
>
> ```
>                                 -- Donald Knuth (probably)
> ```

From a performance standpoint, it probably falls within the 97%.

> "There are two ways of constructing a
>   software design: One way is to make it
>   so simple that there are obviously no
>   deficiencies, and the other way is to
>   make it so complicated that there are
>   no obvious deficiencies. The first
>   method is far more difficult."
>
> ```
>                                 -- C.A.R. Hoare
> ```

From a complexity standpoint, simplicity, clarity, and understandability are good motivations.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery over-use ?

Do not do this

```
$('.link').click(function(){
  $(this).attr("height", "99px");
  $(this).attr("width", "302px");
  $(this).css("left", "329px");
  $(this).attr("position", "absolute");
  ...
});
```

do this instead

```
  .my-class {
    background:url("/images/bg.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height:99px;
    left:329px;
    position:absolute;
    top:419px;
    width:302px;
  }

 $('.link').click(function(){
       $(this).addClass('my-class');
   });
```

unless you absolutely have to [not knowing CSS is not a valid excuse]

Answer (score 2):

The example in the question is over-use IMO not because of performance concerns, but because the plain JavaScript version is considerably more readable.

Similarly, `td.cellIndex` and `tr.rowIndex` are much more readable (as well as faster) than the commonly-given hacks like `$(this).parent().children().index(this)`, and simple properties like `this.checked` is IMO better than `$(this).is(':checked')`.

Within jQuery itself, you should prefer to use jQuery wrapper methods rather than the versions wrapped into non-standard selectors.

```
$('#thing .thing').last()
```

can be fast because the selector will be handed off to the fast built-in `querySelectorAll` call on modern browsers.

```
$('#thing .thing:last')
```

will be relatively slow.

Also watch out for selector string-slinging, which is usually a bad thing:

```
$('div.'+className)
```

is going to break as soon as there's a className with a dot (or various other punctuation) in it. Avoid making a selector string if there's a more reliable way to test.